# German Umlauts are not displayed in Eclipse on the console output

Tags: java, eclipse

German Umlauts are not displayed in Eclipse on the console output

For example, when I run `System.out.println("ä");`, the console does not output the ä, but a question mark. Where do I have to change the encoding so that this is displayed correctly?

Answer (score 2):

For the respective "Run Configuration", there is an "Encoding" setting in the "Common" tab.

[image: 1]

Comment: ...and it inherits it from the project settings (project Properties - Resource - Text file encoding) which inherits it from the Workspace settings (Preferences - General - Workspace).